# Unsupported get request on GET video by id (Facebook Graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to do a get request for video info using the graph api using the following link:

https://graph.facebook.com/10154701535244904?access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET

It always worked, but now its not working for any videos.
It also works for posts, it just don't work for videos anymore.

Comment: Most likely because the access token can't see the video

Comment: Since this is on a user timeline, you are going to need `user_videos` permission from the person who posted that video.

Comment: But this video is public, i used to be able to get the video information without the permission

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which version of the API your request is using? v2.1 of the API was sunset on the 30th of October. If you don't specify a version for your requests, your requsts will now use v2.2.

We've been having similar issues getting a post for an ID. Our app now defaults to v2.2 for all requests unless the version is specified. Playing around with the Graph API Explorer we found that v2.4+ worked for us.

Here are the requests and results we tried in the Graph API Explorer:

/{post_id}?access_token={access_token} -> FAILED

/v2.2/{post_id}?access_token={access_token} -> FAILED

/v2.3/{post_id}?access_token={access_token} -> FAILED

/v2.4/{post_id}?access_token={access_token} -> PASSED

v2.5/{post_id}?access_token={access_token} -> PASSED

/v2.6/{post_id}?access_token={access_token} -> PASSED

/v2.7/{post_id}?access_token={access_token} -> PASSED

/v2.8/{post_id}?access_token={access_token} -> PASSED